# Open fragment from Recyclerview's View Holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My Recyclerview's view holder has a button which should open a bottom sheet dialog for the specific item. I'm building a car app, and the user can add a note to the car he favorites, the recyclerview I'm talking about lists all his favorites and he should be able to add a Note from the favorite fragment. This code needs to open the fragment which takes the note

But a problem occurs, the view holder doesn't recognize getFragmentManager()

```
        mAddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddNoteFragment addNoteFragment = new AddNoteFragment();
            addNoteFragment.setCar(car);
            addNoteFragment.setIcon(mNoteIcon);
            addNoteFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), addNoteFragment.getTag());
        }
    });
```

Code is inside my view holder

Comment: You need to pass your activity’s context when you’re creating your Adapter: MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this) // this as in context in activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a reference to either `Activity` or `Context` so use it as

```
addNoteFragment.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), addNoteFragment.getTag());
//                   ^^^^^^^
//or
// addNoteFragment.show((YourActivityName(context)).getFragmentManager(), addNoteFragment.getTag());
```

Because fragment managers are specific to some activity so either you need to be in an activity to get the fragment manager or you need an activity instance(or cast context to activity) to get it

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter class, set your constructor to take Context as an argument:

```
Private Context mContext;
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

In your holder:

```
try {
    final Activity activity (Activity) mContext;
    fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
catch(ClassCastException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
If(fragmentManager != null) {
    //use your fragmentManager
}
```

Or create an interface in your adapter that has an onClick method to be implemented in your Activity.

Comment: You’re saying you need an Activity instance or a context... that’s what I did..?

Comment: `you need an activity instance(or cast context to activity) to get it`